# Reading and writing byte arrays in .NET Windows Forms

Tags: .net, file-io

Why doesn't the following code work (tested using Word documents and PDF files)?

The saved file launches the correct application, but it is corrupted and will not open.

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    return;

string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filename);
byte[] array = new byte[stream.Length];

SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.FileName = filename;
if (DialogResult.OK != saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog())
    return;

FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
using (FileStream fs = fi.OpenWrite())
{
    fs.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? 
Have you tried opening the files with some text editor and see what they contain?

Comment: Please include the error or exception text that you experience, and indicate the line of code where it occurs.

Comment: Open the saved files with a hex editor, and see what they contain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the File byte array methods for better results.

Also, utilize `using` whenever you are working with disposable objects.

```
        byte[] array;
        string filename;

        using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) 
                return;
            filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            array = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
        }

        using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog())
        {
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = filename;
            if (DialogResult.OK != saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()) 
                return;
            File.WriteAllBytes(array);
        }
```

Comment: @user1125508: You are welcome, and welcome to stackoverflow! Keep in mind that if an answer solves your question, you should click the checkmark next to the answer and, once you have enough reputation, the up arrow above the number next to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filename);  
byte[] array = new byte[stream.Length];
```

You are never actually reading in the bytes, you are just initializing the array to the right *size*, but don't fill in the *data*. That means you are writing a bunch of zero bytes to your new file.

Instead use the framework to your advantage - the `File` class already has a static method to read all bytes:

```
byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
```

Or, if above is really the full scope of what you are trying to do just use [`File.Copy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you are writing an **empty** array. See this line:

```
byte[] array = new byte[stream.Length];
```

And then this line:

```
fs.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
```

You can actually use your first filestream as the data source for the second one by [Reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) all bytes.